# NIFI cluster - cannot insert any processor

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

I just setup a nifi with cluster config using 3 nodes.. Everything loooks normal, I mean the cluster menu appears and all the nodes are connected, but when I try to insert a new processor or upload a template I am getting some error due to some task is currently running.. I checked the task in the nifi-app.log and I found the task is related to a Replicate Request Thread-232.

2023-05-23 21:25:50,237 INFO [Replicate Request Thread-232] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator Received a status of 409 from 0.0.0.0:8080 for request PUT /nifi-api/controller/config when performing first stage of two-stage commit. The action will not occur. Node explanation: Transaction e2501fb0-dca2-44d0-9784-829f42269890 is already in progress.
2023-05-23 21:25:50,237 INFO [Replicate Request Thread-232] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator Received a status of 409 from 0.0.0.0:8080 for request PUT /nifi-api/controller/config when performing first stage of two-stage commit. The action will not occur. Node explanation: Transaction e2501fb0-dca2-44d0-9784-829f42269890 is already in progress.
2023-05-23 21:25:52,989 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.h.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor Finished processing 3 heartbeats in 19974 nanos

I only need to upload the template that I were using before the cluster configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can access the NiFi UI, have you checked the users/policies and verify whether you have necessary privileges?
   [image: NiFi users and policies]

2. Check whether `$NIFI_HOME/conf/users.xml` has your user identity. I have given a sample file for a user with email-identifier `user-name@work.org`

```
<tenants>
    <groups/>
    <users>
        <user identifier="fab6ef41-bbbd-3fb6-a0fb-48baf0b5d84c" identity="EMAILADDRESS=user-name@work.org, CN=nifi_user, OU=GROUPNAME"/>
    </users>
</tenants>
```